# Lambda expression on properties in C#

Tags: c#

I know we can define properties like this:

```
public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
```

But i've seen this:

```
public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
```

this just works, is this the same as:

```
public int TemperatureF { get { return 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556)}};
```

?
I suppose there is not `set` in this case.

Comment: Syntax was added in C#6 for Expression Body Member: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members

Comment: "I suppose there is not set in this case." exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is the same. You can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-implement-a-lightweight-class-with-auto-implemented-properties) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#read-only-properties) as suggested by @BurnsBA.